# String tab in textview programmatically

Tags: java, android, string, layout

I need to put String tab in `textview`. how to do it with android Text view

```
textview1.setText("ABC -  answer");
textview2.setText("ABSDE -  answer");
textview3.setText("SOMETEXT -  answer");

//Required out put
ABC        -  answer
ABSDE      -  answer
SOMETEXT   -  answer
```

Comment: So what do you want to do? Android Tetview will do same.

Answer (score 5):

If you are displaying the text in a fixed-width font, there are ways to pad Strings with spaces. You can use [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) for that. It has `leftPad` and `rightPad` methods.

Another option is by using `String.format()`. For example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s - %s", "ABC", "answer"));
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s - %s", "ABCDE", "answer"));
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s - %s", "SOMETEXT", "answer"));
```

Produces:

```
ABC        - answer
ABCDE      - answer
SOMETEXT   - answer
```

See [Java Format String syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: You're welcome. Just be aware of the fact that it really requires fixed width fonts. Otherwise you'll have to look into other ways to layout these texts.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 textview.setText(String.format("%s \t -  %s", "ABC ", " answer"));
```